# Google Visualization Table - Draw Twice with Different Columns Displayed

Tags: google-visualization

I have a single data source from which I would like to display 2 separate tables, with different columns visible in each (as well as some the same).  I have filters on this and would like those filters to affect both tables.  I can get both to draw and the filters to work, but anytime I hide columns it affects both instead of just one.  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: yes, you can use the [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) to draw the tables. which has a view property where you can apply the filters, rather than on the data table. if you want to share your code, I can help...

Comment: sometimes it just takes knowing that it's possible to get one over the hump.  in working up a jsfiddle to share my code (and with the help of your comment) I was able to get it working.  here is a link to my working jsfiddle for anyone else who is interested: https://jsfiddle.net/d3w4jsm2/